# Quick Action View dialog not dismiss in Android

Tags: android

I used Quick Action View in my App. But when i press on particular item i want to dismiss dialog but its not working. Here is my code please check and let me know the issue please

```
custom_action_bar = (ImageView) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    custom_action_bar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             * "Welcome to settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1, new String[] { "One", "Two",
                            "Three" });

            // create the quick action view, passing the view anchor
            qa = QuickActionView.Builder(view);

            // set the adapter
            qa.setAdapter(adapter);

            // set the number of columns ( setting -1 for auto )
            qa.setNumColumns(1);

            qa.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "qa.setOnClickListener calleddddddddd");
                    dialog1 = dialog;
                    dialog1.dismiss();

                    switch (which) {
                    case 0:

                        break;

                    case 1:

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                    // qa.cancel();
                }

            });

            // finally show the view
            qa.show();

        }
    });



    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Please let me know the issue here

Comment: Could you please post the hole class implementation, to let us where you are doing this implementation.
Your code seems to be fine, i think that the action is being called, but not from UI THREAD!!!

Comment: edited Please check onclick in UI Thread only.

Comment: Have you tested changing Context ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your progress dialog globally

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, from the posted snippet, i think that the problem is on the use of Application context(getApplicationContext()).
Could you please change the getApplicationContext(), view.getContext() on Adapter initialization and let me know if it works.